# query to fetch records for alternate days based on a column

Tags: sql, date

I have a table altstore with a column checkindate which keeps the date. My requirement is to fetch records of alternate days for a month for example of day 1st of the month, then 3rd and so on. Please help me with the sql query which I can use.
Thanks.

Comment: What database server are you using, by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
select * from altstore
where DATEDIFF (day,startingdate,enddate) % 2 is 1
```

here `startingdate` is first date of the month and `enddate` is value in column `checkindate`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `datepart` and `modulo`:

```
select
    *
from
    table
where
    datepart(dd, checkindate) % 2 = 1
    and checkindate between '2011-12-01' and '2011-12-31'
```

Comment: why checkindate restriction of dates (and to 2011)?

Comment: @aF. - Just the way the question was worded made me think that the user wanted alternate days for only one month.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something on these lines:

```
SELECT * from yourtable where date(checkindate)%2 !=0
```